# Android Deep Linking without android:scheme

Tags: android, intentfilter, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I have a activity that apply intent filter to open deeplink, this is my intent filter :

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/..*"
                    android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

my problem is, when user open a link i.e "www.example.com/somepage" from messaging apps e.g Hangout,Whatsapp, Android app chooser doesn't display may apps in its list, it just show all browser app in the options. But when user put "https://www.example.com/somepage" in a message then it works, Android show my app in its App chooser to open the link.
It also doesn't work When I try to remove `android:scheme="https"` from my intent filter.

is there anyone has same problem and have a solution?

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: I know it's been 2 years lol, but did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

**This is expected behavior.**

What the following snippet does is register your app as a handler for the URL scheme `https://`

```
<data
    android:host="www.example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/..*"
    android:scheme="https" />
```

This means your app will be offered as an option for any link beginning with `https://` and containing `www.example.com`. The string  `www.example.com/somepage` doesn't qualify, as it is missing the `https://` part.

You could try adding a *second* filter for `http://` links. I'm not sure if Android automatically infers that as the scheme for web links without a scheme specified, so it's possible this could resolve the issue.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data
      android:host="www.example.com"
      android:pathPattern="/..*"
      android:scheme="https" />

  <data
      android:host="www.example.com"
      android:pathPattern="/..*"
      android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```